# Extracting audio file duration from a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm trying to retrieve the audio duration (mm:ss) of a song that is hosted on my CDN. The audio file is linked here: https://ucarecdn.com/6b1c0d8b-3145-4128-b7ff-ce5420fe154e/ (be aware that pasting this url into your browser will download the audio file direct to your computer (~4mb)).

I have already been able to extract the bpm and now I'd like to determine the length of the song as well. Searching online appears that all I should need to do is:

```
var song = "https://ucarecdn.com/6b1c0d8b-3145-4128-b7ff-ce5420fe154e/";
console.log(song.duration);
```

But that shows `undefined`

I also have been trying this, but receive `NaN`:

```
<audio id="myAudio" controls>
    <source src="https://ucarecdn.com/6b1c0d8b-3145-4128-b7ff-ce5420fe154e/" type="audio">
</audio>

<script>
    function myFunction(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var x = document.getElementById("myAudio").duration;
    console.log(x);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is duration return **NAN** because the audio element did not loaded so

You need 2 things here to solve your problem 
 + first you need to wait till the dom elements downloaded 
 + second you need to listen for the audio loadmetadata event handler then you can access the duration

```js
$(function(){
const ad = document.getElementById('ad');
ad.onloadedmetadata = function() {
   // duration in seconds
   alert(ad.duration);
};
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="ad" src="https://ucarecdn.com/6b1c0d8b-3145-4128-b7ff-ce5420fe154e/" controls></audio>
```